# Displaying tens of thousands of geocoordinates

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Say I have a database of lat/long values stored (e.g. the geocoordinates of businesses). Now, I want the user to be able to search for something like:

> search for all Chinese restaurants in Los Angeles

Is there a way to do this using Google Maps? Would I somehow pass all the geocoordinates? It will be in the tens of thousands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Map API does have view [port biasing](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#GeocodingViewports) and [region code biasing](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#GeocodingRegionCodes) to help search their database but not yours.

Latitude and longitude roughly equate to distance on the ground (1 degree for both latitude and longitude is about 69 miles, see the degree length section for [latitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitude) and [longitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latitude) for more info). Therefore if you stored latitude and longitude in seperate columns, and if you can resolve *Los Angeles* to a lat/long (maybe by using Google's [reverse geocoding](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#ReverseGeocoding)), you code do a simple query to return only the business that are within an approximate distance from the *Los Angeles* lat/long.

This will return results within a square, (or rectangle, but not a circle), that is centered on the *Los Angeles* lat/long. Any result within the square's corner will be greater than the selected approximate distance away from the *Los Angeles* lat/long.

Comment: This is complicated and relies on having to make API calls to get the information I need. Any other solutions?

Comment: Maybe this is only one API call: to get the lat/long of Los Angeles. Then, I use math to figure out if the geocordinates I have in my database are within a certain distance in Los Angeles. This solution might work.

Comment: But -- if I just wanted to group the restaurants by location (say, show total number of Chinese restaurants in Los Angeles or display all restaurants in San Francisco), how would I do that?

Comment: How are you going to use the Google Maps API without calling the API? I have proposed the simplest, but least precise, solution. Indeed you only need one API call: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=los+angeles+CA&sensor=false

Comment: Rough SQL would be for Los Angeles: SELECT * FROM Restaruants WHERE lat>= 33.55 AND lat <= 34.55 AND long >= -117.74 AND long <= -118.74 AND cuisine = 'Chinese' would provide all the Chinese Restaurants within (roughly) 35 miles of the center of Los Angeles. You could use COUNT(*) to get the number of Chinese restaurants.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking show me all results within a radius, or all results within a bounding box then you only face an sql query problem - once you have the central point of the query.

If you want to find all places within a city, then perhaps you can simply have your sql query filter on a field in your database.

```
select title from restaurants where city = "Los Angeles";
```

or if you have accurate zip code coverage:

```
select title from restaurants where postal_code like "<ZIP-STARt>%";
```

If you do not have 100% zip code coverage then consider running a one-off geocoding exercise to bring back the zip code.

(I admit ignorance of how zip codes relate to cities in the US)

Comment: I do want to do something like `select title from restaurants where city = "Los Angeles";`, but Google Maps API prevents me from storing information like that. And I think it'll be a pain for me to do it on my own.

Comment: So are you saying you have a database of restaurants with the coordinates lat, lng but not the city name?

Comment: Correct. I would like to store city name, etc., but Google Maps API says I can't. I don't want to collect the information from my users as I don't trust their input.

Comment: You can use gmaps api to reverse geocode from your existing coordinates.  http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding This is a one-off task that you'd use cURL or similar to do, you cache the results in your database.  This is permitted under gmaps t&cs IF the results are to be displayed on google maps - which I think you are planning to do.